# best practice for user preferences in $HOME in Python

Tags: python, preferences

For some small programs in Python, I would like to set, store and retrieve user preferences in a file in a portable (multi-platform) way.

I am thinking about a very simple ConfigParser file like "~/.program" or "~/.program/program.cfg".

Is `os.path.expanduser()` the best way for achieving this or is there something more easy/straightforward?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
os.path.expanduser("~")
```

is more portable than

```
os.environ['HOME']
```

so it should be ok to use the first.

Comment: os.path.expanduser('~') is a portable solution, but consider using xdg.BaseDirectory (http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pyxdg) to find a proper location for your application specific data on platforms that follow freedesktop.org's XDG Base Directory Specification (http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

Comment: I appreciate the FD standard, but this requires an external module, so I would really go for the stdlib solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.environ:

```
import os
print os.environ["HOME"]
```